# JSF Dynamic Image as div Background

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I generate dynamic images from a backend database using streamed content. They work fine when used with p:graphicImage.

The issue comes when such a dynamic image needs to be the background of div.

How can I use dynamic images created with stream content as a background of a div element?

JSF Controller

```
public StreamedContent imageByCodeInlineWithoutGet(String code) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context.getRenderResponse()) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    } else {

        String id = code;
        if (id == null) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }
        String j = "select s from Upload s where lower(s.code)=:id";
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("id", id.trim().toLowerCase());
        Upload temImg = getUploadFacade().findFirstByJpql(j, m);
        if (temImg != null) {
            byte[] imgArr = null;
            try {
                imgArr = temImg.getBaImage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new DefaultStreamedContent();
            }
            if (imgArr == null) {
                return new DefaultStreamedContent();
            }
            StreamedContent str = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgArr), temImg.getFileName());
            return str;
        } else {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Generating Images Dynamically

```
                                <p:graphicImage cache="false"  value="#{streamedContentController.imageByCodeInlineWithoutGet('header__logo')}"  >
                                </p:graphicImage>
```

I want to use the image as a css background like below

```
                        <style type="text/css">
                            background-image:#{streamedContentController.imageByCodeInlineWithoutGet('header__logo')};
                        </style>
```

or Passing as a parameter.

```
                    <div class="hero__item set-bg" data-setbg="#{streamedContentController.imageByCodeInlineWithoutGet('header__logo')}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Is it possible with JSF or PrimeFaces or any other library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way of sending custom content on a GET request for a specific path is a [`HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Just starting with a kick-off example:

```java
@WebServlet("/images/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private YourEJB imageEJB; // your EJB for images

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // get the image code from the requested path
        String imageCode = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);

        // get the image type and byte array as the content

        response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(/* image type */);
        // OR
        response.setContentType(/* image mime type */);

        response.setContentLength(/* byte array length */); // just 'array.length'
        response.getOutputStream().write(/* byte array */); // just `array`
    }
}
```

---

#### Explanation

This registers a custom [`HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) for the given path (`/images/*` this path can be changed to what you want).
The servlet gets called when the client loads the image via a GET request.

Then you can get the image code from the requested path (`request.getPathInfo().substring(1)` gets the file path and removes the first slash).

Then you have to get the mime type of the image. This is possible by two ways:

- get the basic file extension (`jpg`, `png`, etc.) and get the mime type for the file type from `web.xml` (`mime-type` elements)
- directly get the mime type

Then you must have the byte array that represents the content of the image. Set the response size with `contentLength`.

Then finally write the byte array to the response.

---

#### Usage

The good thing is you can use it everwhere (css, js, plain html, etc.).

Just specify the `/images/*code*` and the image gets loaded.

---

#### See Also

[Omnifaces GraphicImageBean](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/GraphicImageBean) (similar to this solution)